# PHP Passing Variable on the Same Page

Tags: php, parameter-passing

I am creating a project on PHP. But I have a problem. I want to pass some values from a section to another section. For example: In first section I am showing all products, and second section I am showing product details. When I click a product on first section, products values should pass second section. I am sharing my codes. Thanks

First Section

```
<section class="section pb-60 sm-pt-90">
<!-- Portfolio Items -->
<div id="portfolio-gallery" class="portfolio-container isotope-container portfolio-gallery row animated mfp-gallery" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="1200">
    <article class="portfolio-item isotope-item col-md-4 col-sm-6 tasarim">
  <div class="project-container">
    <a href="http://blogaktuel.com//upload/Ekran Alıntısı.PNG" data-size="1080x1440" class="portfolio-gallery__img--main">
      <img src="http://blogaktuel.com//upload/Ekran Alıntısı.PNG" alt="" style="width:360px; height:256px;">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-wrapper">
          <div class="overlay-inner background-dark-5 opacity-70"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="project-details">
      <a href="http://localhost:81/Projeler/kodaktuelOnePage//yeni-proje-mesela"><h4 class="project-title heading-uppercase">Yeni Proje Mesela</h4></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Second Section

```
<div id="detay" class="ed-slide">
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide-content">
      <section class="section sm-pt-0">
        <div class="container">
          <h2 class="text-white text-center animated" data-animation="fadeInDown"><!-- Project Title --></h2>
          <div class="divider divider-alt divider-center divider-light animated" data-animation="fadeInDown" data-animation-delay="300"><span></span></div>
          <p class="lead text-white mb-50 text-center animated" data-animation="fadeInDown" data-animation-delay="600"><!-- Project Info --></p>
          <!-- Project Images etc. -->
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: PHP is a server side language. Page is served once php execution is finished. Either keep the content hidden on page load and display when needed or fetch details via Ajax when needed.

Comment: You have to use javascript / jquery to achieve what you want.

Comment: I got it, thanks for coments PankajMakwana and BilalAkbar

Comment: If I can solve this, I share my solution for other user

Answer (score 0):

You can make that using 2 ways:

-First way: when clicking on a product, you reload the page, and you pass the id in the url, and you display the data in the other section.

-Second way(Best way): via jquery for example, when clicking on a product, you load the data for this product and you display it in the other section.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with jQuery. I am sharing jQuery codes.

```
$(".details").click(function(){
var proje_baslik = $("input[name=proje_baslik]").val();
var proje_aciklama = $("input[name=proje_aciklama]").val();
var proje_url = $("input[name=proje_url]").val();
var proje_fiyat = $("input[name=proje_fiyat]").val();
var proje_resim = $("input[name=proje_resim]").val();

$("#detay .proje_baslik").html(proje_baslik);
$("#detay .proje_aciklama").html(proje_aciklama);

window.location.href = "http://localhost:81/Projeler/kodaktuelOnePage/#detay";});
```

Thanks for all comments